# TFS 2010 tracking build definition changes?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, team-explorer, build-definition

Is there a way to track changes to a build definition in TFS 2010? Please go to 'Team Explorer > ProjectName > Builds' in visual studio to see what I am talking about. You need to have access to a TFS server in order to see what I am referring to. Now once you are in the Team Explorer> ProjectName > Builds, you can create a build definition to compile your csproj or sln files on TFS. What I am wondering is, Is there a way to version these build definitions if I do any changes to existing ones or add a new one?

Answer (score 2):

I got into the same issue when someone from the team modified the Build Definition, I tried to find all the available option but found none except `Xeam Build Definition Extension` which is only supported VS 2012 onward and has some downsides, so finally to get the immediate work around I wrote a small app which returns the `Last Modified By` and `Last Modified Date` and the complete `Build Definition` details which you can compare with previous version to find what got changed.

Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client

```
Private Const RootFolder As String = "C:\TFS Utility Reports\"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' To Get the Build Definition Details
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="teamProjectName"></param>
    ''' <param name="buildDefinitionName"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetBuildDefinitionDetails(teamProjectName As String, buildDefinitionName As String) As String
        Dim buildDefinitionSummary As String = Nothing
        Dim buildDefinitionDetails As String = Nothing
        Dim reportPath As String = RootFolder & "Build Definitions\" & buildDefinitionName
        Dim buildDefinitionDetailsFileName As String = reportPath & "\" & buildDefinitionName & "_" & Date.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Replace("/", String.Empty).Replace(":", String.Empty) & ".txt"
        Dim buildService = CType(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(GetType(IBuildServer)), IBuildServer)
        Dim buildDefinition As IBuildDefinition = buildService.GetBuildDefinition(teamProjectName, buildDefinitionName)
        If buildDefinition IsNot Nothing Then
            GetAllBuildDefinitions(teamProjectName)
            buildDefinitionSummary = buildDefinition.ToString()
            UpdateFile(buildDefinitionSummary, buildDefinitionDetailsFileName, reportPath)
            If buildDefinition.Workspace IsNot Nothing Then
                buildDefinitionDetails = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Last Modified By: {0}, Last Modified Date: {1}",
                                                                                                    buildDefinition.Workspace.LastModifiedBy,
                                                                                                    buildDefinition.Workspace.LastModifiedDate)
            End If
        End If
        Return buildDefinitionDetails
    End Function


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Generate Log/Summary/Report
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="lineToWrite"></param>
    ''' <param name="filePath"></param>
    ''' <param name="folderPath"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Shared Sub UpdateFile(ByVal lineToWrite As String, ByVal filePath As String, ByVal folderPath As String)
        Dim strFileName As String = String.Empty
        lineToWrite = lineToWrite.Trim()
        strFileName = filePath
        Dim di As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
        If Not di.Exists Then
            di.Create()
        End If
        Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(strFileName, True, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
        Try
            Dim strOutput As String
            strOutput = lineToWrite.ToString
            streamWriter.WriteLine(strOutput)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            streamWriter.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to track changes to a build definition. If you have multiple branches / versions you need to build I suggest creating a different build definition.

Some of the properties can be set when you queue the build, so if you want a CI build that does not copy it's output to the drop server, you can have that, but then if you want to deploy a version you can set a drop folder when you queue the build.

In the [TFS Power Toys](http://aka.ms/tfpt) you get a "Clone Build Definition" context menu so you can copy builds easier if you have a lot of settings you want to keep similar.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply. I do have TFS Power tools installed. But it does not solve my purpose to track changes in build definition over time.

Comment: You can't really. If you really wanted to, you can export the definition process parameters as XML at regular intervals, or something similar, but there's nothing build in at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. There is this tool in the vsgallery:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ec36f618-d122-48a3-8236-7d9cd19791ee

I used it with tfs2012. I don't know if it works with tfs2010